# CUDA MPS for OpenCL?

Tags: opencl, nvidia

CUDA MPS allows you to run multiple processes in parallel on the GPU, thus fully utilizing the GPU for operations that don't take full advantage.  Is there an equivalent for OpenCL?  Or is there a different approach in OpenCL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use multiple OpenCL command queues that don't have event interdependencies, an OpenCL runtime could keep the GPU cores busy with varied work from each queue. It's really up to the implementation as to whether this actually happens. You'd need to check each vendor's OpenCL guide to see if they support concurrent GPU kernels.